# Multi-line populist badge

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges

[image]

The badge image (as shown above) takes up multiple lines [here.](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/49/populist) The badge icon is on one line while the badge name is on a separate line.

Comment: I don't get it...why is this a problem? Is something breaking because of it?

Comment: @Mitch I would say something is broken, if the badge appears like that.

Comment: This is a bug very specific to EL&U, as on other sites the badge appears on one line.

Comment: Oh...I don't see the problem in my browser, but in your screen shot it looks like the badge image and the word 'populist' are on different lines. Is -that- the problem? I wouldn't call that a bug, just ... infelicitous.

Comment: I've revised your post to clarify that what you meant was "The image of the Populist badge is on two lines" so that people don't get confused and thing "The newly revised description of the badge runs across two lines".

Comment: Doesn't look like a problem to me. Presumably it happens because the supplementary *"multiple times"* text causes the line on the right to expand to its maximum width. Still not enough to make it all fit on one line, but other badges with other text (on other SO sites) might actually *benefit* from this behaviour. My vote is to stop bothering the backroom boys with trivia where they probably made the right "generic" call already.

Comment: It's clearly an image display gone awry, which I would say makes it a bug.  Whether the devs think it's worthwhile to fix is up to them.  It's pretty trivial, but as a dev (elsewhere) I still like to know about this sort of thing.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Actually, it also happens on Apple.SE and a host of others.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/badges/49/populist

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/badges/49/populist

Comment: http://diy.stackexchange.com/badges/39/populist

Comment: The list goes on.

Comment: And.. what is going on with Populist on Drupal? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/badges/39/populist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this has been fixed.